# Spring data mongodb query with default Value embedded in method name

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to write query in this way?

```
public enum Status {SUCCESS, FAIL}

@Document
public class Machine {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private Status status;
  private boolean test;
}

public interface MachineRepo extends MongoRepository<Machine, String> {
  // This is possible !!
  Machine findByTestFalse();

  // Is this possible ?? <-- Here is the question!!
  Machine findByStatusSuccess();
}
```

Comment: Do you have errors?

Comment: @RomanC sure, NPC is the root cause, property path not found